# approve a jenkinsfile step by a slack button

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, slack, jenkins-job-dsl

i would like to approve a step in a jenkinsfile directly from a slack channel, by clicking on a button at the chat

for example:
jenkinsfile:

```
...
 stages {
        stage('build approval') {      
            steps {
                slackSend botUser: true, channel: 'xxxxx', message: 'please approve the build'
                input message: "Approve deployment", ok: "Yes" // Connected to the slack button
            }
        }
...
```

slack chat:

please approve the build by clicking on <<*button>>*